# Postgresql lock

Tags: node.js, postgresql, locking

I've read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) and couldn't figure out which lock state I need to use for blocking all update/insert/delete commands on the table while allowing select command

Please help me figure out what should replace `???`

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE t1 IN ??? MODE;
INSERT INTO t1(a,b,c) VALUES
    (1,2,3);
SELECT id FROM t1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
COMMIT WORK;
```

Can I execute this command from Node.js using the pool.query command?

Comment: Why do you think you need to lock the table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there's another process that is counting on having a specific set of  id's - the lock will prevent other users from writing to the table and messing the numbering of these id's especially when there are more than one value and limit is bigger than 1.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) states:

> ROW EXCLUSIVE
>
> Conflicts with the SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes.
>
> The commands UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT acquire this lock mode on the target table (in addition to ACCESS SHARE locks on any other referenced tables). In general, this lock mode will be acquired by any command that modifies data in a table.

So in order to change data you need that lock. To prevent anyone from changing data in some table you have to lock it with conflicting mode (see [table 13.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#TABLE-LOCK-COMPATIBILITY) in the same documentation page). You can see there are 4 such modes:

- SHARE
- SHARE ROW EXCL.
- EXCL.
- ACCESS EXCL.

To [lock the table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-lock.html) do:

```
LOCK TABLE "my_table" IN SHARE MODE;
```